# How can I display all the blogs where this user is administrator in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress

Given is the user id..

How can I display all the blogs where this user is administrator?

I tried,

```
<?php
$user_id = 2;
$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) {
    echo '<li>'.$user_blog->blogname.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

However, it will return all the blogs where user has access to regardless if it is an administrator or just a subscriber. But all i want to display is those blogs where this user is administrator.

Is this possible? If yes, How? Please help.

Comment: Put this question in the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ so you can get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
global $wp_admin_bar;
foreach( $wp_admin_bar->user->blogs as $blog ) {
...
```

I'm not 100 % sure what it contains for non admins but there's a chance it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use current_user_can() function , to identify if loggedin user is administrator or not.

```
if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    //Some Condition
}
```

[Relevant link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

Comment: This could actually be used to solve the OP's question using the array he's already got, but the correct function to use is user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) since the user in question is not necessarily the current user.